# History and results of the GE90 B747 Test

Tags: aviation-history, boeing, boeing-747, boeing-777

In [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Electric_GE90) article, I read about the B747 testbed for the B777 GE90 engine. Where can I find more information on that airplane?

Comment: What do you want to know? Looks like a normal passenger 747 with a different engine mounted on the port inboard pylon. Probably equipped with some additional engine monitoring but not sure its much different than a "stock" 747. In fact, [here is a (really short) video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NYYXoy7xbik) of that aircraft/engine combo, and [an article](http://www.gereports.com/post/86519922565/computers-flying-economy-new-747-test-jet-is-a/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may read more in this article:

- [Boeing 747-121 General Electric Engine Testbed, c/n 19651](http://www.air-and-space.com/Boeing%20747-121%20General%20Electric%20Engine%20Testbed.htm)

As mentioned this is the B747 with construction number 19651.

From this article above:

> On March 9,1992 the former Pan Am Boeing 747-121 was registered to
>   General Electric Aircraft Engines (GEAE) at the Mojave Airport in
>   Mojave, California.
>
> At the Mojave Airport General Electric removed all
>   passenger coach seating from the former Pan Am 747 and installed three
>   engine data-gathering systems.
>
> General Electric strengthened the
>   747-100 airframe to allow it to be capable of flying 747-300 type
>   maneuvers, needed for high - inlet - angle, fan - stress and inlet -
>   stability testing.
>
> GEAE would attach the test engine to the number two
>   engine pylon located on the aircrafts left wing.
>
> <sup>(Source: [air-and-space.com](http://www.air-and-space.com/Boeing%20747-121%20General%20Electric%20Engine%20Testbed.htm))</sup>

[image]
<sup>(Source: [Airliners.net](http://www.airliners.net/photo/1330828/L/))</sup>